# Flask webform upload file and use it as attachment without saving in between

Tags: python, flask, upload, sendmail, attachment

the case:

1. Created a webform with flask to upload files
2. On post, i want to use the uploaded file directly as an attachment added to a mail.
   Without saving the uploaded file inbetween actions.
   (so mainly, through a webform I want to mail the uploaded files)

On the post action, I read the uploaded file list like:

```
files = request.files.getlist("file")
```

After that I use the code below to create a testmail with the attachments. The mail is send, and I have attachments files but they are all 0kb and useless.

Anyone a clue how to do this trick without saving the files first (uses spaces) before sending?

All input is welcome,

Regards,

Skay

```
    # Define email sender and receiver
    email_sender = os.environ['EMAILSENDER']
    email_password = os.environ['EMAILPASWOORD']
    email_receiver = Emailreceiver

    # Set the subject and body of the email
    subject = 'Mail test'
    body = """
    Check if it works
    """

    em = MIMEMultipart()
    em['From'] = email_sender
    em['To'] = email_receiver
    em['Subject'] = subject
    em.attach(MIMEText(body))
    #em.set_content(body)

    for file in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        
        #with open(file.filename, 'rb') as file_open:
        #file.save(file.filename)
        part.set_payload(file.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment; filename={}'.format(file.filename))
        em.attach(part)

    # Add SSL (layer of security)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    # Log in and send the email
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
        smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, em.as_string())
```

I tried saving files (works), and read them back for sending as attachments.
Mail works, but in the option without the save option, the files are empty.